# Namenode not running

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, hadoop, hbase

After complete setup of hadoop when I tried to run hadoop then I found that (by jps) namenode is not running. I searched in log files and I found a exception that was "Directory /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible." . So I created i directory in /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name by sudo mkdir -p /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name and give this complete rights. Now after restarting the hadoop I saw that namenode is still not rumming and I found this exception "dFSNamesystem initialization failed.java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.". I have formatted the namenode "{hadoop-dir}/bin hadoop namenode -format" and it formatted fine but exception in  namenode logs are still present. Here my namenode logs are given below

```
2012-04-11 13:19:09,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = hbase.com.com/192.168.15.20
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.205.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-security-205 -r 1179940; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Fri Oct  7 06:20:32 UTC 2011
************************************************************/
2012-04-11 13:19:09,899 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2012-04-11 13:19:09,959 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2012-04-11 13:19:09,965 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2012-04-11 13:19:09,965 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2012-04-11 13:19:10,443 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2012-04-11 13:19:10,469 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2012-04-11 13:19:10,490 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2012-04-11 13:19:10,492 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2012-04-11 13:19:10,666 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2012-04-11 13:19:10,666 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB
2012-04-11 13:19:10,666 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2012-04-11 13:19:10,666 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304
2012-04-11 13:19:11,005 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=com
2012-04-11 13:19:11,006 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2012-04-11 13:19:11,006 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=false
2012-04-11 13:19:11,025 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2012-04-11 13:19:11,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2012-04-11 13:19:11,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2012-04-11 13:19:11,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2012-04-11 13:19:11,211 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1277)
2012-04-11 13:19:11,212 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1277)

2012-04-11 13:19:11,217 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at hbase.com.com/192.168.15.20
************************************************************/
2012-04-11 13:28:38,247 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = hbase.com.com/192.168.15.20
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.205.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-security-205 -r 1179940; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Fri Oct  7 06:20:32 UTC 2011
************************************************************/
2012-04-11 13:28:39,037 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2012-04-11 13:28:39,101 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2012-04-11 13:28:39,107 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2012-04-11 13:28:39,107 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2012-04-11 13:28:39,626 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2012-04-11 13:28:39,643 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2012-04-11 13:28:39,667 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2012-04-11 13:28:39,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2012-04-11 13:28:39,842 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2012-04-11 13:28:39,844 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB
2012-04-11 13:28:39,844 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2012-04-11 13:28:39,844 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304
2012-04-11 13:28:40,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=com
2012-04-11 13:28:40,183 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2012-04-11 13:28:40,184 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=false
2012-04-11 13:28:40,210 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2012-04-11 13:28:40,211 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2012-04-11 13:28:40,281 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2012-04-11 13:28:40,393 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2012-04-11 13:28:40,414 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name does not exist.
2012-04-11 13:28:40,417 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1277)
2012-04-11 13:28:40,429 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1277)

2012-04-11 13:28:40,430 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at hbase.com.com/192.168.15.20
************************************************************/
2012-04-11 13:32:59,596 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = hbase.com.com/192.168.15.20
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.205.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-security-205 -r 1179940; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Fri Oct  7 06:20:32 UTC 2011
************************************************************/
2012-04-11 13:33:00,423 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2012-04-11 13:33:00,489 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2012-04-11 13:33:00,495 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2012-04-11 13:33:00,496 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2012-04-11 13:33:00,973 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2012-04-11 13:33:00,998 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2012-04-11 13:33:01,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2012-04-11 13:33:01,023 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2012-04-11 13:33:01,167 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2012-04-11 13:33:01,167 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB
2012-04-11 13:33:01,167 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2012-04-11 13:33:01,167 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304
2012-04-11 13:33:01,471 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=com
2012-04-11 13:33:01,474 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2012-04-11 13:33:01,474 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=false
2012-04-11 13:33:01,493 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2012-04-11 13:33:01,497 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2012-04-11 13:33:01,590 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2012-04-11 13:33:01,748 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2012-04-11 13:33:01,776 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name does not exist.
2012-04-11 13:33:01,787 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1277)
2012-04-11 13:33:01,788 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1277)

2012-04-11 13:33:01,793 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at hbase.com.com/192.168.15.20
************************************************************/
```

Comment: possibly duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447885/no-namenode-error-in-pseudo-mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty easy - format your namenode

```
mcbatyuk:hadoop bam$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

12/04/11 21:04:55 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = mcbatyuk.local/192.168.10.102
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1214675; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Thu Dec 15 16:36:35 UTC 2011
************************************************************/
Re-format filesystem in /Users/bam/hadoop/name ? (Y or N) Y
Format aborted in /Users/bam/hadoop/name
12/04/11 21:04:57 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at mcbatyuk.local/192.168.10.102
************************************************************/`
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After executing `/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/bin/hdfs namenode -format` the error was solved.

Comment: but what if the cluster is running ,formmating my namenode means losing all found data ,isn't there are any solutions to solve